# How could I expose rqt_graph to tcp port?

Tags: python, c++, ros, robotics, ros2

I wrote a project to control a vehicle with ros2. I access this vehicle through ssh and write code directly from there.

Clearly, there is no GUI and I would like to expose the result of rqt_graph on a tcp port so I can see it. Is there any way?

I've tried to use [Rosboard](https://github.com/dheera/rosboard/) but I didn't find anything to view graph like rqt_graph.